# Stylized 2D shadows for 3D model

Tags: shaders, 2d

I am trying to create a shader that replicates the shadows from the original Sonic Riders, here I have the in game model set up with a toon shader, but I am unsure how to fully recreate this effect.

any help is greatly appreciated! [image]

[image]

Comment: Personally, I really rate  [Lightning Boy Studio's series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpWI2rU8iF0) on a pretty comprehensive approach to toon shading.

Comment: Try using a bright, far of Point Lamp and set it's size to 0. Then use one Toon Shader and set it's size to .95